# Activate first workbook after closing second one?

Tags: excel, vba

Situation:

1. Open workbook A.
2. Code in A opens workbook B.

   - B is now the active WB.
   - Code in B ends with `ThisWorkBook.Close`
3. B closes, so A appears.

The problem is: I can't get ANY `Activate` events in WB A to fire automatically after WB B closes.

But if I close WB B manually, using mouse to 'x' out the WB, or via the menus, then WB A triggers `Activate` events.

Somehow using VBA to close WB B prevents WB A Activate events from triggering.

Same results in Excel 97 and 2003

Am I missing something, or is there a workaround??

Comment: The activate statement in my answer below seems to work fine for my test case.  I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want I guess.  If you could make a sample set of books that would be helpful, but a lot of work for you.

Comment: Do you know if your parent workbook gets activated BEFORE the child workbook gets closed? That's the problem I seem to have.

Answer (score -1):

Before opening workbook B set workbook A to a defined name:

```
 Dim wb as workbook

 set wb = activeworkbook

 'run your code


 wb.Activate
```

EDIT:

Put this in each workbook_close() event for your child books:

```
  windows("A.xlsm").activate
```

This will activate your master sheet anytime one of your child wbs closes
(you may want to add a check that A.xlsm is open, and if not open it or exit the sub)

Comment: What if you/your user gonna keep on opening multiple books (>2) and close them randomly? How do you track that?

Comment: id suggest naming all of your workbooks and avoid using activate or select at all.  Therefore by using wb.range etc you can do anything to any workbook you have open from one block of code.  wb can be named anything you want and you can have any number of them.  You need to use logic and general sense to keep track of what is open and what is not.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The part where @scott wrote 'run your code, is where I would open workbook B. But right after opening B, the next line gets executed and brings control right back to WB A. I need A to open B, and stay on B until, e.g., a button is clicked on WB B, which will call thisworkbook.close, and then return to WB A. Which is when I need A to call its activate events.

Comment: if you post an example of your code and process it will be easier to make suggestions

Comment: @scott  'A.xls and Control Toolbox button on sheet 1 of A.xls    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  

    Workbooks.Open ("D:\excel\B.xls")  
    
End Sub  
----------------  
'B.xls and Control Toolbox button on sheet 1 of B.xls  

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  

    ThisWorkbook.Close  
    
End Sub  

Thanks for your continued help!!!!!!

Comment: @user1830217 Will these two books always be referencing each other, or is this intended to be dynamic?

Comment: Good question. Just referencing each other. Basically, I have a master workbook with buttons that I want to use to open other workbooks (and keep them as separate workbooks). And then when those child workbooks are closed, just go back to the master workbook. Then use the WB or WS activate commands in the master workbook (e.g. A.xls in previous comment) to process various file activity when it is known that the child workbook is closed (for instance, change the file attribute of closed workbook to read-only). Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer, basically if you just place an activation snippet in the workbook_close event of each child book, whenever that book is closed, it will activate the master book automatically

Comment: Putting Workbooks("A.xls").Activate in the Workbook_BeforeClose event is acting odd. It does not activate Workbook A. Instead, it just stays on WB B when I click the button whose sole command is "ThisWorkbok.Close". Perhaps VBA sets enableEvents to False when running Workbook_BeforeClose? Would you try out your code and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: I should have made it clear that I need the child workbook B to be closed before activation of master/parent WB A because I would like, for instance, to change WB B to read-only after it has closed, and intend to do this when control/activation returns to WB A (parent). Unless there is some other way to achieve this.